# How NOT to display one figure per page?

Tags: appendix, pnas

I am trying to finish a paper for a PNAS submission. It is advised to put one figure per page in the supporting information, but I do not want to do that since there is a clear order in my appendix that I would like to stay in place.
The template provided by PNAS (https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pnas-template-for-supplementary-information/wqfsfqwyjtsd) automatically puts one figure per page.

I have looked everywhere in the source but I can't find the command that produced this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You should complain with PNAS rules. However, see if you can avoid this limitation with inserting more images in one `figure` float.  Maybe as subfigures.

Comment: the code is in `pnassupportinginfo.sty`. But you shouldn't change this. They probably will simple reject your submission if you violate such an explicit rule.

Comment: Thanks! I finally found the command. I will contact the support from PNAS to know if this is allowed. The author's center doesn't seem to have strong guidelines for supporting information, only for main texts.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue – has there been any resolution, yet?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue and noticed that one can simply overwrite figure placement by giving alternative placement options, like so

```latex
\begin{figure}[tb]
   ...
\end{figure}
```

The PNAS Supplement style file defines the placement `p` as default for figures, which explains the original observation.